# Runnings tests in visual studio after publish profile finishes successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, visual-studio-2015, publish-profiles

I have an ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2015 that contains a number of publish profiles to deploy my website to various IIS web servers on an intranet. I also have a project containing a set of Selenium tests. Both of these projects are part of the same solution. I want these tests to run on a specified web server if a publish profile finishes successfully. The closest I have got to this is enabling 'Run Tests After Build' in Visual Studio which runs the tests when the project is built manually but doesn't seem to be linked to the pubish profiles finishing.

I don't have access to Team Foundation Server which I beleive is one way to acheive what I want so I was wondering if there were any other solutions, possibly through explicitely running the tests through PowerShell.